# javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: ejb

I am try to implement generic Dao using hibernate and wildfly-10.1.0.Final

**BaseDao.java**

```
BaseDao<T, PK extends Serializable> implements BaseDaoI<T, PK>

@Override
public T save(T t) {
    try {
        this.entityManager.persist(t);
        return t;
    } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**StudentDao.java**

```
public class StudentDao extends BaseDao<Student, Long>{

public StudentDao(EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(Student.class, entityManager);
}}
```

**StudentBean.java**

```
 @Stateless
public class StudentBean implements StudentBeanLocal {

@PersistenceContext(name = "com.erick_SchoolManagementSystem_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
EntityManager em;
StudentDao stud = new StudentDao(em);

@Override
public Student add(Student student) {
    return stud.save(student);
}
```

**RegisterStudent.java**

```
@EJB
StudentBeanLocal studentbean;
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirst_name(request.getParameter("first_name"));
    student.setLast_name(request.getParameter("last_name"));
    student.setUsername(request.getParameter("user_name"));
    student.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
    if(studentbean.add(student)!=null){
        response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
    }else{
        response.sendRedirect("Register.jsp");
    }
```

When I fill in the form to register and submit, I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.erick.schoolmanagementsystem.dao.BaseDao.save(BaseDao.java:34)

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete stacktrace? Also make sure you are not trying to persist a null object.

Comment: check the full stacktrace as diplayed in the browser:- https://notepad.pw/stacktrace

Comment: It is not the "correct" stacktrace. Check 2 thins. If you are persisting a null entity or if entityManager is null. Also do not return null on catch exception. Print the stacktrace. (catch (PersistenceException pe) {
        pe.printstacktrace(); return null;
    })